# Controlling Shader Node Sliders outside of Shader Mode

Tags: materials, node-editor, shader-nodes

It's not a major issue but I felt that if someone knew how to do it it could come in handy. I have a tendency to use a fair few textures using sliders, particularly mix shaders or emission nodes which I want to use to switch between different settings. Now as far as I know the only way to control these sliders is to open the shader editor and interact directly with the nodes, and it can get mildly irritating.

Now sliders connected to the direct output node appear on the materials tab, does anyone know a technique to make sliders on other nodes appear on the materials tab or as well? Or another way to adjust the sliders outside of shader mode.

Comment: You can expand the nodes in the properties window with the small arrows to the left and control any sub nodes, albeit with some digging

Comment: Thanks, that'll help out a lot in the future.